# How to fire an event whenever there is a read operation in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

We have 2 databases in our application. Main is MySql and for logging purposes we use mongoDB. We need to capture data whenever there is some operation on MySql DB and store it in MongoDB. As far I am able to capture the Insert, Update and Delete operations. But don't know how to get data whenever there is some read operation. We need to know who has read whose data. I have tried on internet a lot but not able to find any solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create a listener on `postLoad` event - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload